# Vox parser Python

Tags: python, numpy

Ищу парсер vox фалов в python numpy массив. Нашел вариант, но нерабочий.
Пытался использовать:
https://github.com/alexhunsley/numpy-vox-io
Исходный код:

```
import math
import sys
import coloredlogs
from pyvox.parser import VoxParser

coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG')

m = VoxParser('cube.vox').parse()

img = m.to_dense()
```

И выводит ошибку:
`pyvox.parser.ParsingException: Unknown chunk type: b'nTRN'`
Как исправить и есть или аналоги для чтения vox файлов через python ?

Comment: https://github.com/gromgull/py-vox-io/issues/6

Comment: И как это поможет решить проблему?

Comment: 1) Вы не одиноки с ошибкой 2) Ошибке минимум 1 год 3) Можете там отписаться и возможно автор библиотеки обратит внимание на ошибку 4) В той проблеме говорится что ошибка возникает у `new MagicaVoxel format`, а значит на старых форматах ошибки нет и наверняка можно или доработать парсер для поддержки нового типа чанка, или, возможно, найти программу для конвертации в старый 5) Ссылка на проблему может быть полезна, а вы ее не указывали

Comment: А так, погуглив `python MagicaVoxel` первой ссылкой было: https://formats.kaitai.io/magicavoxel_vox/python.html, а четвертой https://pypi.org/project/voxelfuse/ . Мб что-то из этого будет полезно